# Как извлечь текст из pdf файла отделавшись малой кровью?

Tags: pdf

нужно извлечь из словаря отдельно слова и отдельно их значения, в словаре больше 10к слов, вручную делать будет сложновато и нудно, есть ли какие нибудь варианты как сделать это быстрее, эффективнее?

Comment: В смысле какой софтиной текст выцепить, или как в коде программы достать текст из pdf?

Comment: примерно так:
**рука** часть тела
**автомобиль** транспортное средство;

нужно извлечь отдельно то что написано полужирным и отдельно то что означает слово